# How to use a c# Image object in itextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Is there any solution to convert a c# Image object to an iTextSharp compatible image to be used inside the pdf.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The class `iTextSharp.text.Image` has a method called `GetInstance()` that has 18 overloads, 3 of which accept a `System.Drawing.Image`.

```
iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor);

iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor, Bool);

iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat);
```

In almost every case you want the first one and you can just pass `null` for the second parameter (unless you want to force transparent pixels to be a certain color).