# Create an iTextSharp.text.Image from System.Drawing.Image [GetInstance overload not available]

Tags: c#, image, itext

I have a System.Drawing.Image and would like to add it to a PDF in a specific position. The only problem is that the overload for

`iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor);`

is not available for some reason. I keep getting compiler error:

`Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Uri, bool)' has some invalid arguments`

I know this question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139984/how-to-use-a-c-sharp-image-object-in-itextsharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548166/how-to-create-a-itextsharp-text-image-object-startng-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap) but without the overload I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: Can you verify the types of data that you are passing into the GetInstance method? It looks like the compiler is assuming you want a different overload, based on one or more of the variables you are sending.

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? iText 7 for C# was completely redesigned. There is no longer a `GetInstance()` method for `Image`. Instead you need to use a constructor. Maybe you're using some version of iTextSharp to which the (valid!) answers you found don't apply.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I cloned their [Github](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) page yesterday, and used the dll. If it is iText 7, then would the `GetInstance()` method still appear? As of right now it has 15 overloads, none of them accepting a System.Drawing.Image. Edit: I looked up the constructor for iTextSharp.text.Image but it only has two overloads. One for a Uri, and another that takes iTextSharp.text.Image

Comment: @ryancdotnet I am passing a System.Drawing.Image and a BaseColor. This is the exact call I am making: `iTextSharp.text.Image iTimage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, BaseColor.WHITE);`

Comment: iText 7 can be found on [github](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/tag/7.0.0)/ so can iText 5: [github](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases/tag/5.5.9) (your link isn't the download page). Your allegation that none of the `GetInstance()` methods in iText 5 is accepting `System.Drawing.Image` is false. See [line 751 of Image.cs](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Image.cs#L751). Why do you claim that `GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image image, BaseColor color)` doesn't exist when it's obviously there?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I can see that it is there, but when compiling with the proper parameters, I am getting the compiler error above. [This link](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Image.cs#L585) goes to the definition from the repository I cloned. Above it there is an `#if DRAWING` compiler directive. In fact, none of the overloads within the `#if Drawing ...  #endif //drawing` are working. Does this have something to do with it?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I found the problem. The default build configuration is for debug_woDrawing. I changed it to release and now everything works as it should. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments, but I'm adding a real answer for further reference.

The `GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image image, BaseColor color)` exists, but if you look at the code, you see that it is preceded by an `#if DRAWING` compiler directive. None of the `System.Drawing.Image` overloads within the `#if Drawing` ... `#endif` will be taken into account when building with the default configuration `debug_woDrawing`. You need to change the configuration to `release` if you want to compile everything yourself.

Or use the [official release](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases/tag/5.5.9) if you don't want to run into these kind of problems.